# Rest Template setter used in CloudFoundry client lib

Tags: cloud-foundry

We are trying to use the `CloudFoundryClient` (org.cloudfoundry.client.lib) to utilize the `REST` interface to add applications, create services etc

We see an issue in the `getToken` method of `org.cloudfoundry.client.lib.oauth2.OauthClient` where it tries to access the setRestTemplate method of the `org.springramework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.implicit.ImplicitAccessTokenProvider.`

On looking up the source, we see that the setter for `RestTemplate` in the `ImplicitAccessTokenProvider` has been removed on 29th Aug, which is what is causing this inconsistency.

Could you please advise and let us know if we should try with a version of spring-security-`oauth` prior to this change and a link where we could find this?

Comment: Hi Sandip, reviewing the code at https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-java-client/blob/master/cloudfoundry-client-lib/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/client/lib/oauth2/OauthClient.java shows the following: ImplicitAccessTokenProvider provider = new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider();
  provider.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
  OAuth2AccessToken token = null; , revealing the setRestTemplate request, are you referring to this statement?

Comment: If I have interpreted this correctly, can you try again with this version?

Comment: @eightyoctane : Thanks for writing in. yes I am referring to the same statement you have mentioned- ImplicitAccessTokenProvider provider = new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(); provider.setRestTemplate(restTemplate); OAuth2AccessToken token = null;  and which version you are mentioning in your second comment ?

Comment: It looks like the new lib detects if the Template is null, then sets it internally. Have you tried making the lib available locally, then removing the statement to get it going? I'm also filing a Jira to fix this.

Comment: @eightyoctane : Thanks. The code change does work when we tried but we wanted to check when a newer version of the lib will be made available

Comment: Sudipta, can you try using this version? http://www.springsource.org/node/3611

Answer (score 1):

The cloudfoundry-client-lib uses 1.0.0.RC1 of spring-security-oauth where this method is available. Please refer to [SPRING SECURITY OAUTH 1.0.0.RC1 IS RELEASED](http://www.springsource.org/node/3611)